# unable to setup net.tcp bindings for wcf application running on IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, wcf, iis-8, bindings

I am trying to set up `NET.TCP` bindings for a `WCF` application deployed on `IIS`. I have already added net.tcp to `Enabled Protocols` of application, but when I am trying to add net.tcp binding, its throwing the error shown below:

[image]

I have also activated the Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation. NET.TCP services are also running.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can setup by command prompt

appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" –+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']

Comment: to be more precise: the actual command for me was `appcmd.exe set site /site.name "Default Web Site" /+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']` to add the binding